# I want fetch only particular category products (women) products from database in Django

Tags: python-2.7, django-models, django-templates, django-views

```
 {% regroup products by categories as products_by_category %}
    {% for c in products_by_category %}
       <h1>{{c.grouper}}</h1>
       <ul>
        {% for p in c.list %}
            <li>{{p.name}}</li>
            <li> <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ p.image.url }}" alt="IMG-PRODUCT" height="290" width="190"></li>
            <li>{{ p.price }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
       </ul>
    {% endfor %}
```

This is my Views.py

```
def product_list_women(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.filter(name='women', slug='women')
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=categories)
    return render(request, 'product_women.html',{'category': category,'categories':categories,'products':products})
```

And this is my models.py file

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True ,db_index=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name', )
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('demo:category', args=[self.slug])

    def get_products(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(category=self)


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name', )
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('demo:product_detail', args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

I want to list only women products instead of all the products category wise. I want to make pages which displays the products when I click on that category. This code shows all the products category-wise. How can I do that?

Comment: Try replacing `products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)` with `products = Product.objects.filter(available=True, category__name='women')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Django's Many-to-one relationship Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/):

> Related managers support field lookups as well. The API automatically follows relationships as far as you need. Use double underscores to separate relationships. This works as many levels deep as you want. There’s no limit.

Therefore, you can do something like that:

```
products = Product.objects.filter(available=True, category__name='women')
```